# Assigning multiple variables in Python line-by-line analysis

Tags: python

I'm writing something that analyzes a directory line by line in Python. Parts of my text follow this format:

```
SMITH, JOHN
(123) 456-7890
(134) 193-2495
(284) 282-6829
```

I want to assign the three phone numbers to three different variables (i.e. phone1, phone2, phone3) all associated with the person John Smith. I'm thinking of approaching it by testing to see if the variables have already been assigned. For example, if phone1 already has a phone number assigned to it, Python knows to assign it to phone2. If phone2 has also been assigned, then it automatically assigns it to phone3. What's the easiest way to write something that does this? I'm open to any other suggestions as well.

Comment: If that's all the information you have, and if there's no limit to the number of phone numbers a person can have, you should use an array.

Comment: Why don't you use a list?

Answer (score 3):

Why not store your phone numbers in a list?  Then, you're not limited to three per person.  Assuming your contact list were stored as a dictionary, you could access them like this:

```
contacts = { 'SMITH, JOHN' : ["(123) 456-7890", "(134) 193-2495", "(284) 282-6829"] }

# printing third phone number for SMITH, JOHN (note that numbering starts at 0)
print contacts['SMITH, JOHN'][2]

# printing number of phone numbers for SMITH, JOHN
print len(contacts['SMITH, JOHN'])

# adding a new phone number for SMITH, JOHN:
contacts['SMITH, JOHN'].append("(818) 555-1212")
```

Of course you'd probably want to do something a little more sophisticated than that to handle first & last name, other necessary fields, etc, but that would be a way to handle multiple phone numbers in a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}

class phone():
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.phone = list(arg[:3])
    def add(self, arg):
        for i in self.phone:
            for j in arg:
                if i == j:
                    print("error")
                    return 0
        if len(self.phone) + len(arg) <= 3:
            for j in arg:
                self.phone.append(j)
        else:
            print("error")

def add(name, *arg):
    if d.get(name):
        d[name].add(arg)
    else:
        d.update({name : phone(arg)})
```

---

```
>>> add("SMITH, JOHN", "(123) 456-7890")
>>> add("SMITH, JOHN", "(134) 193-2495", "(284) 282-6829")
>>> d["SMITH, JOHN"].phone 
['(123) 456-7890', '(134) 193-2495', '(284) 282-6829']
```